# Get custom attributes across assemblies

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have Assembly `A`, where `MyCustomAttribute` is located.

Now I have Assembly `B`, where I have `reference` to assembly `A` and I use in assembly `B`  `MyCustomAttribute`.

Now I want to get all inctanses of  `MyCustomAttribute` in Assebmly B.

I try something like:

```
public static void Registration()
{
    List<MyCustomAttribute> atrr = new List<MyCustomAttribute>();

    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

    var types = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                    where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(MyCustomAttribute))
                    select type).ToList();
}
```

And other ways -- but I can't get `MyCustomAttribute`.

**UPDATE**

My attribute

```
namespace NamespaceOne.Attributes
{
    [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false,
    Inherited = false)]
    public class MyCustomAttribute: Attribute
    {
      ......
    }
}

Now the second Assembly(second project - ASP WebApi):

namespace SecondNamespace.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        [MyCustomAttribute]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
         MyStaticMethod.Registration(); // THIS Class andmethod in First class library - where located attribute 
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Did you verify that `GetCallingAssembly()` actually returns `B`?

Comment: Yes. But inside I dont see my custom attribute

Comment: Could you show your attribute, as well the type that implements it?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
public class MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
}

[MyCustom]
public class SomeClassWithAttribute
{

}
```

Then in the console:

```
var assembly = typeof(SomeClassWithAttribute).Assembly;

            var types = (from type in assembly.GetTypes()
                         where Attribute.IsDefined(type, typeof(MyCustomAttribute))
                         select type).ToList();
```

I get SomeClassWithAttribute with in the types list. @C.Evenhuis is correct, you are probably getting the wrong assembly in the "GetCallingAssembly" method. Its always more reliable to get an assembly by getting a type that you know is present in that assembly and then getting the Assembly property from that.

Comment: Attribyte and method where i use this attribute in different assemblies

Comment: You need some other way of getting the target assembly... is the method finding that attribute on types always looking in a specific assembly or its a generic method? If its generic, is it always supposed to return the attribute that its supposed to find in the assembly of the calling code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static void Registration()
{
    List<RegistryAttribute> atrr = new List<RegistryAttribute>();

    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();

    var types = assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => 
                    type.GetCustomAttributes().Any(x => x is typeof(MyCustomAttribute))).ToList();
}
```